# file not found exception while uploading file to web server?

Tags: android

I am using following [tutorial](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html) to upload image file to webserver.

and getting file not found exception here.

```
try {
         File uploadFile = new File(uriString); 

// file path i receive **content:/media/external/images/media/2**

        FileInputStream fis =   this.openFileInput(uploadFile.getName()); // **ERRoR HERE**

        HttpFileUploader htfu = new HttpFileUploader("http://finditnear.sigmatec.com.pk/inbox/send_remote_reply","noparamshere", uploadFile.getName());
        htfu.doStart(fis);
        } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
        }
```

image file exists there but still it giving me error.

Can any one guide me what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

content:/media/external/images/media/2 is incorrect file name, it's a Uri.
So this line

```
FileInputStream fis =   this.openFileInput(uploadFile.getName());
```

Should be replaced with

```
InputStream fis=this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(new Uri(uriString));
```

Comment: Uri constructor does not exist.
anyways thanks yes i got the answer
InputStream fis = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uriString));

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: no i did not :( 
and second thing i just want to read image and upload so i might need reading permission Right?
and thanks for reply.